# Are there any applications that map and show the health of the hard disc?

Tags: software-recommendation, hard-drive

I was wondering if there is an application that can tell us (in an easily understandable way...like in a chart) how healthy our hard disc is. If the boot sector is healthy...etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on dash and then type disc, you will get a disc management tool, called Disk Utility, that shows you that and more.

Disk utility is tools for formating, partitioning, and manage harddrive or removable storage such flash drive/disk drive.

[Ubuntu disk utility can do following activity](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2010/06/ubuntu-1004-disk-utility-tools_28.html):

1. Benchmark Harddrive and Removable Device

Utility to check how fast your storage to read and write data, you can use this utility to compare a performance form one to another.

1. Smart Data Self test

Smart data would check and show us the disk healty using attribute and its assessement. using his utility we can llook after harddrive temperature and bad sectors.

1. Mount/unmount  device
   This utility is for mount and unmount device.
2. Check and repair filesystem
   Utility for check and repair file system, some activity may cause lost of data, especialy for this action please backup your data
3. Edit Partition
   Edit partition is for resize partition, change a file system type, marge a multiple partition.
4. Format Partiton
   This action is for clean all partition table and schema in a partition then make a new one.
5. Edit File System Label, and
   This action is for rename a partition name or lable.

8.Delete Partition
This action is for delete a partition table.

## The best info about Disc Utility in my opinion can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37659/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-disk-utilities/)

Comment: It's called Disk Utility.  It's very useful, especially since it lets you quickly and easily see the SMART info for the discs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always give GSmartControl from the repositories a spin.  It'll run both short & long tests built into the drive, also displays SMART info.